# How to get 'child controllers' reference of NavigatorIOS in React-native?

Tags: javascript, ios, navigation, react-native

I have just learned react-native for several days.Now I come across a question on NavigatorIOS component. I want to know if it is possible to get 'child controllers' of NavigatorIOS in react-native just like in native objective-c(with UINavigationController.viewControllers). I want to get the reference and call some update method.

```js
_addNavigator: function (component, title) {

    var data = null;

    var temp = <NavigatorIOS
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      barTintColor='#007AFF'
      titleTextColor="#fff"
      tintColor="#fff"
      translucent={false}
      initialRoute={{
        component: component,
        title: title,
        passProps: {
          data: data
        }
      }}/>;

    componentArray.push(temp);

    return temp;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the reference of child controller in NavigatorIOS, but we can use EventEmitter lib to meet our requirement.
EventEmitter is something like NSNotification. For more information, check the link [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter)